# SQL Server JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help explain to me how when I have 12 rows in table A and 10 in B and I do an inner join , I would get more rows than

in both A and B ?

Same with left and right joins...

This is just a simplified example. Let me share one of my issues with you

I have 2 views ; which was originally SQL on 2 base tables Culture and Trials.

And then when attempting to add another table Culture Steps, one of the team members separated the SQL into 2 views

Since this produces an error when updating(modification cannot be done as it affects multiple base tables), I would like to get

back to changing the SQL such that I no longer use the views but achieve the same results.

One of the views has

```
SELECT       some columns
FROM            dbo.Culture RIGHT JOIN
                     dbo.Trial ON dbo.Culture.cultureID = dbo.Trial.CultureID LEFT         OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 ON dbo.Culture.cultureID =     dbo.TrialCultureSteps_view_part1.cultureID
```

The other TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 view

```
  SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Culture.cultureID,
 (SELECT        TOP (1) WeekNr
  FROM            dbo.CultureStep
  WHERE        (CultureID = dbo.Culture.cultureID)
  ORDER BY CultureStepID) AS normalstartweek
  FROM            dbo.Culture INNER JOIN
  dbo.CultureStep AS CultureStep_1 ON dbo.Culture.cultureID = CultureStep_1.CultureID
```

So how can I combine the joins the achieve the same results using SQL only on tables without the need for views?

Comment: If you have 5 rows in Table A and 2 matching rows (say by ID) in Table B, when you JOIN/INNER JOIN every row in A matches every row in B... so your result would be 10 rows.  You need to either add additional ON clauses to reduce this fanning out, or aggregate one of the tables via a sub-query so its a many-to-one, instead of many-to-many join.

Comment: As for a new query -- can you show us some sample data from the tables, as well as what you'd want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The comments explain the JOIN issues. As for rewriting, any views could be replaced with CTEs. 
One other way to rewrite the query, would be : (Though having sample data and expected result would make this easier to confirm that it's correct)

```
;with TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 AS
(
Select Row_number() OVER (Partition BY CultureID ORDER BY CultureStepID) RowNumber
, WeekNr
, CultureID
) 
SELECT       some columns
dbo.trial LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Culture ON dbo.Culture.cultureID = dbo.Trial.CultureID LEFT OUTER JOIN
TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 ON dbo.Culture.cultureID =     dbo.TrialCultureSteps_view_part1.cultureID and RowNumber=1
```

Access code, I'm less familiar with the syntax, but I know that Row_Number() isn't available and I don't believe it has CTE syntax either. So, we'd need to put in some more nested derived tables.

```
   SELECT       some columns
    dbo.trial LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Culture ON dbo.Culture.cultureID = dbo.Trial.CultureID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (  Select cs.CultureID, cs.WeekNr FROM 
            (     SELECT CultureID, MIN(CultureStepID) CultureStepID
                  FROM   dbo.CultureStep
                  GROUP BY CultureID
            ) Fcs INNER JOIN 
          CultureStep cs ON fcs.cultureStepID=cs.CultureStepID 
    ) TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 ON dbo.Culture.cultureID =     TrialCultureSteps_view_part1.cultureID
```

Assumptions here, is that CultureStepID is a PK for CultureStep. No assumption that a step must exist for each Culture entry.

Comment: How can I do similarly using Access?

Comment: I've updated the answer for approximate access code. It's uglier, and as I've stated, I'm not an access expert, so there may be better ways of doing it.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked after a little modification but takes a lot of time

Comment: The thing is : it is no longer updateable after adding the TrialCultureStep_view table so I want to make it in such a way that the 3 tables are the ones joined(Culture,Trial,CultureStep)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! [This link](http://blog.grio.com/2013/02/an-intro-to-resolving-duplicate-results-in-sql-queries.html) might be a good place to start in your understanding of JOINs.  Essentially, the 'problem' you describe boils down to the fact that one or more of your sources (Trial, Culture, or the TrialCultureSteps view) has more than one record per CultureID - in other words, the same CultureID (#1) shows up on multiple rows.

Based solely on that ID, I'd execute the following three queries.  Anything that is returned by them is the 'cause' of your duplications - the culture ID shows up more than once, so you'll have to JOIN on more than just CultureID.  If, as I half-suspect, your view is the one that has multiple Culture IDs, you'll need to modify it to only return one record, or change the way that you JOIN to it.

```
SELECT *
FROM Trial
WHERE CultureID IN 
  (
    SELECT CultureID
    FROM Trial 
    GROUP BY CultureID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
ORDER BY CultureID 

SELECT *
FROM Culture
WHERE CultureID IN 
  (
    SELECT CultureID
    FROM Culture 
    GROUP BY CultureID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
ORDER BY CultureID 


SELECT *
FROM TrialCultureSteps_view_part1
WHERE CultureID IN 
  (
    SELECT CultureID
    FROM TrialCultureSteps_view_part1 
    GROUP BY CultureID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
ORDER BY CultureID
```

Let me know if any of these return values!

Comment: Many thanks and sorry for the late reply. The first one displays results